# VS2005 Setup project - program asks for installation media when started for the first time by another user

Tags: visual-studio-2005, setup-deployment

I have a very simple VS2005 deployment project that aims to install for all users on a PC.

All the application files are written to %Program Files%\MyProg. A shortcut is created in the start menu and the startup folder. No registry settings or anything else are created. I have set 
'InstallAllUsers' to true.

The created MSI runs fine and installs the software. It works without any problems when running under the user account from which it was installed.

When logging in as another user, the start menu and startup icons are present. It attempts to launch the application however an installation window pops up and states that 'the feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.' The installer will only proceed if pointed to the original MSI file.

Why does this happen? I want my application to be installed *completely* for all users when it is installed by a single user.

**edit: Solution**

*I was getting similar event log messages as shown on [this](http://www.windowsdevelop.com/clickonce-setup--deployment-projects/msi-issue--reinstall-app-for-every-login-user-2791.shtml) page. In my case it turned out to be as simple as ensuring that the User's Program Menu had its 'AlwaysCreate' attribute turned to false. If it was true, windows would try and recreate the folder when a new user logged in. This somehow required the invocation of the installer and thus resulted in the 'please insert the installation media' prompts.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually kind of hard to say without some more information.  I would recommend checking on the rights in the installed folder (seeing if only the one who installed it has rights) and also checking the file list for the directory (to make sure VS didn't automatically place some files in the user profile).  Let me know what comes out from those two steps and we can try to keep digging if that didn't shed any light on it.

Comment: Appreciate you helping out with a boring problem - the bounty is yours if we can nut this out.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the offer, but I need a bit more info (namely the answers to the questions).

Comment: Also do you set the InstallAllUsersVisible attribute to false?  That may help alleviate the problem.

Comment: And I found this for you that might help walk you through it.  It is specific to VS2005. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/445kc47k%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Adkins - absolutely, I'll provide whatever info might prove useful. I'm just not at work at the moment.

Comment: @Adkins - I had InstallAllUsersVisible as true, and selected install for all users when testing the MSI. How do you think this is related?

Comment: @Adkins - I followed that msdn tutorial to the letter when creating the MSI.

Comment: @Adkins - I think you are on to something when you suggest it may be related to permissions. I will do some tests with restricted and admin accounts when I'm back at work.

Comment: @Alex just as a test I would recommend setting InstallAllUsersVisible to false and see what happens.  If the same behavior comes out then we can move on from that option all together. If it works with that selected, then we know the problem and can start working towards solution.

Comment: @Alex also check your Advertise property.  This should be set to false.

Comment: @Adkins - you get the bounty for your willingness to help. You sound like a top bloke.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind chances are this is most def not specific to Visual Studio, look at this MS [support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828376) here where the same message is coming back for office.

Comment: I appreciate your point, however in this case the deployment project within Visual Studio is the only part of the process I can change.

Comment: I am suggesting you use the fact that it is not Visual Studio specific to understand the problem and make according changes

Comment: The causes in that article are not relevant to my case. Do you have any other links which might indicate why an installer might act this way?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I thought I'd add another cause and solution in case the above didn't work for you.

There is a bug in VS Setup and Deployment Projects which results in registry values being entered into HKCU instead of HKLM irrespective of the InstallAllUsers property being set to true.

You must use Orca msi editor to change the registry root for "DesktopFolder" and "ProgramMenuFolder" from either 1 or 2 to -1. The issue cannot be resolved via VS.

http://www.qa.downappz.com/questions/vs-2010-deploys-per-user-features-during-install-which-require-access-to-install-media.html